# Why does my jade file not process my css file?

Tags: css, node.js, express, pug

I have a node app that has three jade files, where they all connoted through the extends method...
The parent template, home.jade, is:

```
html
    head
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='../public/stylesheets/style.css', type="text/css")
    body
        p.title home
        block out_home
```

Don't worry about the last line. Its irrelevant. The problem is that the style.css is not being found (console shows 404 on /style.css). The layout of the files is the standard one made my express:

```
app/
   node_modules/
   public/
         images/
         javascripts/
         stylesheets/
                    style.css
   app.js
   routes/
   views/
        home.jade
```

^^ shows whats relevant.

My style.css:

```
body {
  padding: 50px;
  font: 14px "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: red;
}

.title{
    color:green;
}
```

Why is jade not finding my style.css?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the destination for your generated HTML?

Comment: home.jade is in the views folder

Comment: What is the destination for your **generated HTML**? Your stylesheet is sourced in using a relative path, so if your HTML files aren't generated on the same level as your Jade templates the path won't resolve correctly.

Comment: Here is a similar solution to which I posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32028798/5183619 I hope this helps you out! :)

Answer (score 2):

Jade does not process your css files. Browser does.

`href='../public/stylesheets/style.css'` is a probably invalid location. Does your app have any static middleware (i.e. express.static) set up? Anyway, it should probably be `href='/stylesheets/style.css'` instead.